# how can i separate the mainDomain and the subDomains use mod-rewrite with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, infinite-loop

I want to redirect subdomains on my site if they are queried, but if I do not query, I want to redirect it to a different domain.
I have reached some codes by searching the internet, but I have not improved.
If I can not tell what I want to do, I want the following url and file structure to be the same as I showed.

```
public_html/
|____.htaccess (main htaccess)
|____index.php (php empty)
|____mainDomain/
|     |_____.htaccess (without subdomain htaccess)
|     |_____index.php
|     |_____public/
|     |      |____.htaccess (application htaccess)
|     |      |____index.php
|____subsDomain/
|     |_____ucgen/
|     |_____testFolder/
```

**main htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.metehanboy\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subsDomain/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) subsDomain/%1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]

RewriteRule    ^$    mainDomain/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) mainDomain/$1    [QSA,L]
```

**without subdomain htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule    (.*)  public/$1    [QSA,L]
```

**application htaccess**

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?hedef=$1 [PT,L]
```

I added cpanelden subdomains but infiniteloop happens when I run the subdomain, how can I fix this?

example subdomain link: http://ucgen.metehanboy.com/example/example
other link: http://metehanboy.com/authentication/index

mainDomain folder include mvc php app
subsDomain folder includes test application scripts

**Apache Error Log**

```
[Wed May 02 14:16:26.044185 2018] [core:alert] [pid 3117] [client 95.70.153.106:59513] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:16:26.043954 2018] [core:alert] [pid 3117] [client 95.70.153.106:59513] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:15:42.256845 2018] [core:alert] [pid 2690] [client 95.70.153.106:59497] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLogLevel', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:15:42.256734 2018] [core:alert] [pid 2690] [client 95.70.153.106:59497] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLogLevel', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:15:34.964648 2018] [core:alert] [pid 2641] [client 95.70.153.106:59496] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLogLevel', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:15:34.964434 2018] [core:alert] [pid 2641] [client 95.70.153.106:59496] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLogLevel', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:15:21.351847 2018] [core:alert] [pid 2696] [client 95.70.153.106:59491] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLogLevel', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:15:21.351768 2018] [core:alert] [pid 2696] [client 95.70.153.106:59491] /home/metehanboy/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLogLevel', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 02 14:13:47.582923 2018] [core:error] [pid 3117] [client 95.70.153.106:59459] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://ucgen.metehanboy.com/
[Wed May 02 14:13:47.582877 2018] [core:error] [pid 3117] [client 95.70.153.106:59459] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://ucgen.metehanboy.com/
[Wed May 02 14:13:46.839964 2018] [core:error] [pid 3118] [client 95.70.153.106:59457] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://ucgen.metehanboy.com/
[Wed May 02 14:13:46.839899 2018] [core:error] [pid 3118] [client 95.70.153.106:59457] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://ucgen.metehanboy.com/
[Wed May 02 14:13:39.737762 2018] [core:error] [pid 2696] [client 95.70.153.106:59446] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://ucgen.metehanboy.com/
[Wed May 02 14:13:39.737686 2018] [core:error] [pid 2696] [client 95.70.153.106:59446] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://ucgen.metehanboy.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

In cPanel, you can add subdomains *adjacent* to your main domain, instead of a subdirectory. Why do you need that over-complicated structure? What's the benefit? Use something like this and save yourself the headache:

```
public_html/
 |____.htaccess (application htaccess)
 |____index.php
public_html_ucgen/
 |____.htaccess (subdomain htaccess)
 |____index.php
```